# Reading input from console in F# (as a sequence of lines)

Tags: beginner, functional-programming, io, f#

Consuming input line-by-line until the end is often useful. In C# I would write the following loop:

```
while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null) {
    // ...
```

I wanted to do this using "idiomatic" F# (which to me includes avoiding `let mutable`) and I came up with this:

```
let rec readlines = seq {
    let line = Console.ReadLine()
    if line <> null then
        yield line
        yield! readlines
}
```

The last line shows the following warning

> Warning FS0040: This and other recursive references to the object(s)
>   being defined will be checked for initialization-soundness at runtime
>   through the use of a delayed reference. This is because you are
>   defining one or more recursive objects, rather than recursive
>   functions. This warning may be suppressed by using '#nowarn "40"' or
>   '--nowarn:40'.

The warning would suggest I am actually not writing idiomatic F# (as warnings usually point out problematic code). Is there a better way to write the function that avoids the warnings?

Comment: How are you invoking this function? The rules for code review don't allow me to post my version of this with the `()` addition in @MarkSeeman's answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you have there is a **value**, but you probably want it to be a **function**:

```
let rec readlines () = seq {
    let line = Console.ReadLine()
    if line <> null then
        yield line
        yield! readlines ()
}
```

Comment: was this meant to be `yield line` instead of `yield v`? There is a pending edit on this post by another user making the change to `yield line` and I want to make sure before accepting it.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2012, I'm getting a type constraint mismatch on the `yield! readlines ()` line. Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus What does the error message say?

Comment: Must have been a weird alignment thing. The error is gone. Thanks for inquiring.

Answer (score 8):

Mark's response does answer as to the warning you received.

An alternate approach could be

```
Seq.initInfinite // (1)
    (fun _ -> Console.ReadLine())
|>  Seq.takeWhile (fun line -> line <> null) // (2)
```

Edit: Could be restructured and more succinct as

```
 fun _ -> Console.ReadLine()
 |>  Seq.initInfinite // (1)
 |>  Seq.takeWhile ((<>) null) // (2) (3)
```

1. [Seq.initInfinite<'T> Function (F#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370429.aspx)
2. [Seq.takeWhile<'T> Function F#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370332.aspx)
3. [Partial Application](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/partial-application/)

Comment: Thanks for a very helpful alternative. I was also searching for a non-recursive function example using the `Seq` methods.